# Segmentation fault when catching exceptions in a libpthread linked app ( linux, C++ )

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, segmentation-fault, try-catch

I have this piece of code here:

These are functions used to create and stop a pthread:

```
void WatchdogController::conscious_process_handler_start() {

    if ( debug ) cout << "WatchdogController: starting conscious process thread" << endl;

    cn_pr_thread_active = true;

    if ( pthread_create( &cn_pr_thread, NULL, conscious_process_handler, this ) < 0 ) {
        cn_pr_thread_active = false;
        throw WatchdogException( "Unable to start new thread" );
    }
}

void WatchdogController::conscious_process_handler_stop() {

    if ( debug ) cout << "WatchdogController: stopping conscious process thread" << endl;

    cn_pr_thread_active = false;

    int *retval;

    pthread_join( cn_pr_thread, ( void ** )&retval );

    if ( *retval < 0 ) {
        delete retval;
        string err = string( "Error returned by conscious_process_handler(): " ) + string( pthread_err );
        throw WatchdogException( err.c_str() );
    }

    delete retval;
}
```

I use select() in function passed to pthread, and when stopped it returns an error resulting in return value from pthread being negative, but that's not the issue, I'll fix it later - problem is, that when the exception is thrown here:

```
throw WatchdogException( err.c_str() );
```

and caught here:

```
try {
        watchdog_controller->hardware_watchdog_stop();
        watchdog_controller->unconscious_process_handler_stop();
        watchdog_controller->conscious_process_handler_stop();
    }
    catch ( HardwareWatchdogException &e ) {
        cerr << "Error stopping hardware watchdog!" << endl;
        cerr << e.get_reason() << endl;
        string err = string( "Exception thrown by hardware watchdog controller" ) + string( e.get_reason() );
        if ( log ) write_log( err.c_str() );
        delete watchdog_controller;
        return -1;
    }
    catch ( WatchdogException &e ) {
        cerr << "Exception cought when exiting!" << endl;
        cerr << e.get_reason() << endl;
        string err = string( "Exception cought when exiting" ) + string( e.get_reason() );
        if ( log ) write_log( err.c_str() );
        delete watchdog_controller;
        return -1;
    }
```

I get segmentation fault then trying to access the object at this point:

```
cerr << e.get_reason() << endl;
```

What could be the reason?

Reference &e points to something, but it seems as if the address was invalid.

Here's the exception class:

```
class WatchdogException {

    public:

        /**
            @brief      Default constructor
        */
        WatchdogException() : reason() {
        }

        /**
            @brief      Overloaded constructor - setting the error message
            @param      why         Error message
        */
        WatchdogException( const char *why ) : reason( why ) {
        }

        /**
            @brief      The destructor
        */
        virtual ~WatchdogException() {
        }

        /**
            @brief      A getter for the error message
            @return     Returns a string containing error description
        */
        virtual std::string get_reason() const {
            return reason;
        }

    protected:

        /**
            @var        reason      String containing the error message
        */
        std::string reason;

};
```

Comment: does it make any difference if you caught it by const ref?

Comment: Nothing strikes me as obviously wrong here.  Can you get a backtrace in gdb?

Comment: When run under gdb it freezes on pthread_join - I think it has something to do with gdb not passing signals correctly - how do I configure gdb to pass all signals to program?

Comment: Been a while since I worked with pthreads what is the declaration of pthread_err?

Comment: That's just a member std::string I use to pass error descriptions

Comment: I use g++ with -pthread --Wall -g parameters

Comment: 1) What version of the gcc ?
2) What version of the STL (STLport or native) ?

Comment: Oh, it's pretty old - I'm working on an embedded system

gcc version egcs-2.91.66 19990314/Linux (egcs-1.1.2 release)

It's a 2.4.29 kernel, but I can't seem to find the stl version, how do I check it?

Comment: Well, sorry, your STL library is one what is shipped with the compiler.

Comment: Could you check for the sake of testing this variant of get_reason() :

virtual const std::string& get_reason() const {
 return reason;
}

or 

virtual const char* get_reason() const {
 return "test-reason";
}

Comment: Both checked - nothing changes, still getting segmentation fault

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with the code you posted.  The problem must be something happening elsewhere behind the scenes.  Can you get a backtrace in gdb and try to print the state of the exception object at the time of the segfault?

Comment: Re gdb freezing on pthread_join, I find that odd.  That means the thread is not returning.  How does cn_pr_thread terminate?  I see you have a cn_pr_thread_active flag.  Do you signal the thread to check the flag with a condition variable?

Comment: cn_pr_thread_active flag is a volatile bool member var, There is a while loop in the thread: while ( wd_ctrl->cn_pr_thread_active ) { ... } ... pthread_exit( ( void * )ret ); - select() ensures, that the condition is checked every 0.5 second

Comment: When not run through gdb thread will return normally

Comment: It's difficult to debug a segmentation fault without a backtrace.  I would recommend trying to reproduce the segfault under simpler conditions.  Try commenting out the pthread_join temporarily, and retval check, and just throw the exception.  See if the segfault still happens.  If it does, run it under gdb and see if you can get a backtrace.

Comment: That's funny, without pthread_join exception is caught without problems :/

Comment: Are you sure the segfault is even related to the exception?  Could it be the segfault is happening in another thread, (perhaps as it terminates), and just happens to coincide with the exception getting thrown?  Again, a backtrace would clarify things.

Comment: I just can't reproduce the error - segmentation fault occures only if pthread_join function is called, if the thread is killed using pthread_kill( cn_pr_thread, 9 ) or not ended at all I can catch the exception properly.

Comment: Just a wild guess: do you ever actually allocate any memory for retval?

Comment: Is your thread detached or joinable?

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that you are not properly allocating memory for `retval`, or that somehow you are returning an invalid pointer from cn_pr_thread, and that is why you get a segmentation fault when you call `pthread_join`.

Comment: I'm passing an uninitialized pointer, but I allocate memory for an integer inside the thread.

What do you mean by saying potentially? Is it possible, that the function would go past the throw statement?

Comment: Can you show where you're allocating memory for retval? As for the double delete, you're correct: it shouldn't get past the throw statement. I wasn't reading it carefully enough.

Comment: it doesn't matter if you've dynamically allocated the memory for the returned data inside the thread, you need something already allocated to copy it into.

Comment: int *ret = new int( 0 ); right at the beginning and then later I'm setting the return value right before pthread_exit

Comment: @Peeter, no, I think we are wrong.  Archwimiliuopoczański is doing the correct thing here.  Pthread_join copies the address of the value returned by the terminating thread into the retval.

Comment: @Archwimiliuopoczański, you seem to be doing the correct thing, but I am still leaning towards saying it must be something to do with retval, because you don't get the segfault when you comment out pthread_join.

Comment: I edited my post, because I am not sure exactly what the issue is here, but I am pretty confident it is something related to retval.  Can you recheck the code to make sure you are returning a properly allocated pointer from cn_pr_thread

Comment: That's interesting - I've run the program through valgrind and discovered a memory leak ( I called delete instead of delete[] on an array ) in function passed to the thread - this seems to fix it - no more segfaults... sorry for the problem, I never thought a memory leak could break the entire thread...

Answer (score 0):

In WatchDogException's constructor, are you remembering the pointer to the c-string passed in or are you making a copy of it.

If you're simply storing the pointer then when "err" goes out of scope when the exception is thrown the pointer returned by c_str() will be bad, hence your seg fault when you try and use it.

Comment: WatchDogException makes an internal copy of the C string, so this is not the issue.